# Can not access to a link name on xwiki

Tags: syntax, xwiki

When i'm trying to put a link in a xwiki page like for exemple:

[[3.2.1>>3.2.1]]

3.2.1 is a page that exist .

When i  click on the link ,it's looking for a page with this name 3.2
when i try simple names it works.
Does anyone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XWiki uses the dot as separator between the space and the page.
So if you write `Space.Page` it will look for a page `Page` in space `Space`. (If you just use `Page` it looks for that page in the current space).

If your page name has a dot in it, you need to escape it in the reference part of the link (the one after the `>>`) to prevent being interpreted as a space-page separator, like:
`[3.2.1>>3\.2\.1]]`

Better even use `[3.2.1>>doc:3\.2\.1]]` so XWiki knows you are linking to a wiki page (`doc:`) i.e. instead of an attachment (`attach:`), web page (`url:`) etc ...

Answer (score 0):

[3.2.1>>doc:3.2.1]] resolve my problem